# Dilation of a Voronoi cell in a nilpotent Lie group

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, lie-groups, nilpotent-groups

Let $N$ be a nilpotent Lie group equipped with some left-invariant metric $d$ and a family of dilations $\{\delta_t\}_{t \in \mathbb{R}_+}$. Suppose that there is a collection of points $\{x_i\} \subset N$ such that $d(x_i, x_j) > M,\, i \ne j$ for some large constant $M$. Take one of the points, say $x_0$, and consider the Voronoi cell $V = \{x \in N \mid d(x, x_0) < d(x, x_i) \mbox{ for every } i \ne 0\}$. Now dilate the cell using $x_0$ as a center, i.e. consider $V_t = x_0\delta_t(x_0^{-1}V)$. Is it true that if $t < 1$ (but can be very close to it) and $C > 0$ is given, we can find $M$ large enough that $d(V_t, N \setminus V) > C$ (for any choice of $\{x_i\}$)?

In fact, is it even true that $V_t \subset V$?

If I understand correctly, by [1] we might as well assume that $N$ is stratified and $d$ is the Carnot-Caratheodory metric. In that case, metric $d$ obeys the nice scaling law
$$d(\delta_t(x), \delta_t(y)) = td(x, y).$$

[1] Emmanuel Breuillard, *Geometry of locally compact groups of polynomial growth and shape of large balls*, Groups Geom. Dyn. 8 (2014), 669–732

Comment: Do you assume that $\delta_t$ are homotheties with respect to $d$?

Comment: @YCor In the case of a stratified group that's what happens, yes. I added that to the question. In the general case, I think it's true asymptotically. Thanks!